# Getting crash when perform click on view

Tags: android, unit-testing, onclick, android-espresso

I am getting a crash while performing the testing using **Esprresoo**. Please any one helps me to resolve this issue.

Here is my code

```
 onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.list_slidermenu))
 .atPosition(0).perform(click());
 onView(withId(R.id.text_notssn).perform(click());
 onView(withId(R.id.ll_back).perform(click());
```

I am getting crash for ll_back view. My crash report is

android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with id

Comment: Could you post your xml and and screenshot of layout inspector of the Page where this crash is happening (Tools -> android -> layout inspector)?

Comment: i used the same view name to several layouts

Comment: please post a complete stacktrace of the error. Duplicated ids are given the same value and should not cause any errors.